# Extra Where when using Join in Doctrine Query Language

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have the following code in my Entity Repository class:

```
 $qb
        ->select('d')
        ->addOrderBy('d.dtrDate', 'DESC')
        ->where($qb->expr()->isNotNull('d.deletedAt'))
        ->leftJoin('d.user', 'u')
        ->where('u.id = :user_id')
        ->setParameter('user_id', $user->getId());
```

So basically, I dont want to select an entity where deletedAt property is not null. However it gives me a query like this:

>

```
 SELECT 
  d0_.id AS id_0, 
  d0_.dtr_date AS dtr_date_1, 
  d0_.clock_in AS clock_in_2, 
  d0_.clock_out AS clock_out_3, 
  d0_.total_time AS total_time_4, 
  d0_.memo AS memo_5, 
  d0_.last_update_IP AS last_update_IP_6, 
  d0_.created_at AS created_at_7, 
  d0_.updated_at AS updated_at_8, 
  d0_.deleted_at AS deleted_at_9, 
  d0_.user_id AS user_id_10 
FROM 
  daily_time_record d0_ 
  LEFT JOIN user u1_ ON d0_.user_id = u1_.id 
WHERE 
  u1_.id = ? 
ORDER BY 
  d0_.dtr_date DESC
```

As you can see my first where is not being called. So how can i work on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the documents, or read the ORM source to see how things work actually. TO be short, the answer to your question is:

```
$qb
        ->select('d')
        ->leftJoin('d.user', 'u')
        ->where($qb->expr()->isNotNull('d.deletedAt'))
        ->andWhere('u.id = :user_id')
        ->setParameter('user_id', $user->getId())
        ->orderBy('d.dtrDate', 'DESC');
```